# PyXB: generating class names in Unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8, pyxb

Can somebody point me to the right direction as I'm unable to generate binding classes with `PyXB` when element names are non ASCII?

The minimal reproducible example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Town" type="xs:string" />       
        <xs:element name="Дом" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(look for the `<xs:element name="Дом" type="xs:string" />` where I use cyrillic.
The encoding of the file is `utf8`.
However, when I try:

```
pyxbgen -u example.xsd -m example
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergey/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 210, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 9, column 26

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sergey/anaconda3/bin/pyxbgen", line 52, in <module>
    generator.resolveExternalSchema()
.......
```

which points to the cyrillic name of the element. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF8 is spelled `"utf-8"` in XML and in Python.

```
lilith[33]$ head -1 /tmp/cyr.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
lilith[34]$ pyxbgen -u /tmp/cyr.xsd -m cyr
WARNING:pyxb.binding.generate:Element use None.Дом renamed to emptyString
Python for AbsentNamespace0 requires 1 modules
```

That PyXB generates an element named `emptystring` instead of one named `Дом` is problem, though.  PyXB was designed long before Python 3 and unicode support, and it goes to great effort to convert text to valid Python 2 identifiers.

Since you're using Python 3 it should be possible to bypass that conversion, but it's not quite trivial.  Track [issue 67](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb/issues/67), or if there's a Cyrillic transliteration you prefer the technique demonstrated [here](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb/blob/next/examples/unicode_jp/pyxbgen_jp) for Japanese might work.